# Counting number of letters and words in a text in c programing

Tags: c

I try to write a program that count words and letters in a text that taken from a file that exist in harddrive. But this program just count number of letters of first line.what can I do? please give your idea about this program. please debug my code in your compiler and help me to improve it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int letter(const char sentence[ ]);
int words(const char sentence[ ]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char sentence[100];
    const char *filename = "test.txt";
    FILE *cfPtr;
    if (argc == 2)
        filename = argv[1];
    if ( (cfPtr = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL ) {
        printf( "File '%s' could not be opened\n", filename );
    }
    else {
        int total = 0;
        int total2 =0;
        while (fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, cfPtr))
            total += words(sentence);
        total2 +=letter(sentence);
        printf("%d\n", total2);
        printf("%d\n", total);
        printf("****%s",*cfPtr);
        fclose(cfPtr);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
int words(const char sentence[ ])
{
    int i, length=0, count=0, last=0;
    length= strlen(sentence);
    for (i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if (sentence[i] == ' '||sentence[i] == '\t'||sentence[i] == '\n')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
int letter(const char sentence[ ])
{
    int i, length=0, count=0;
    length= strlen(sentence);
    for (i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if ((sentence[i]>'a'&&sentence[i]>'z')||(sentence[i]>'A'&&sentence[i]>'Z'))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: As a first step, you may want to deobfuscate your code into C.

Comment: `please debug my code in your compiler` We want to **help** you, we do not want to do your job. A better question would be "How can I debug this code?" ...

Comment: Hey guys, please don't downvote, he is a new user. We must not discourage anyone. Its a minor error. :)

Comment: @Vivek No, it's a ***huuuuuge*** error. And the question is very bad. And OP didn't make any effort to do his own debugging. So we do downvote.

Comment: `(sentence[i]>'a'&&sentence[i]>'z')||(sentence[i]>'A'&&sentence[i]>'Z')` Wrong maybe

Comment: lots of mistakes in this single code

Answer (score 2):

You are closing file in `while()` loop you want it out of it.

```
while (fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, cfPtr))
    total += words(sentence);
    total2 +=letter(sentence);
    printf("%d\n", total2);
    printf("%d\n", total);
    printf("****%s",*cfPtr);
    fclose(cfPtr); //<------- you want it out of loop
}
```

Comment: thank you.....my question is how can I change my code to it work correct(in counting letters)?

Comment: @user2506489 your code contains a number of mistakes,which i can't figure out why cannot you see,wrong use of braces,pointers,declarations just have a relook

Answer (score 0):

The corrected else part of `main`:

```
    else {
        int total  = 0;
        int total2 = 0;

        while (fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, cfPtr)) {
          total  += words(sentence);
          total2 += letter(sentence);   // <<< this must be part of the while loop
        }

        printf("%d\n", total2);
        printf("%d\n", total);
        // printf("****%s",*cfPtr);  <<< this is nonsense and will most likely crash

        fclose(cfPtr);   
    }
```

And think about this condition in `letters` which is obviously wrong (I let you find out by yourself as an exercise):

```
(sentence[i] > 'a' && sentence[i] > 'z') || (sentence[i] > 'A' && sentence[i] > 'Z')
```

BTW: C allows empty lines and white spaces in order to make the source code more readable.